# Get DxGrid Column FieldName from within the IvalueConverter Convert Function

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have a Devexpress DxGrid with two Columns with ComboboxEdit CellTemplate

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="grid">
    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
       <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Size_ID" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DimensionComboBox}"/>
       <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Color_ID" CellTemplate="{DynamicResource DimensionComboBox}"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
</dxg:GridControl>
```

in my app.xaml i defined a template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DimensionComboBox" >
                <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="PART_Editor"  DisplayMember="Grp_Property_Desc" ValueMember="Grp_Property_ID" >
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemsSource>
                        <Binding Path="Data">
                            <Binding.Converter>
                                <local:GridComboBoxItemSourceConverter/>
                            </Binding.Converter>
                        </Binding>
                    </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemsSource>
                </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
            </DataTemplate>
```

I would like to know the column field name in my converter in order for me to return data according to the column which called the converter

```
Public Class GridComboBoxItemSourceConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

#Region "IValueConverter Members"

    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert

'if field name is color_id then return data for color_id

'if field name is size_id then return data for size_id

    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to create converter class for each column, I do have many other columns to convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Could create a datatemplate for each column and specify the column name in the converter parameter

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without a second datatemplate?